# Javascript Second into Minutes:Seconds

Tags: javascript

I am working on a clock that needs to display seconds into a

### minutes:seconds

format.

I have worked on some auxiliary functions for display, but I have never really gotten the full display. Here is some of my code:

```
    var time = 1500;
    //Must declare timeHandler as global variable for stopTimer()
    var timeHandler;
    //Set intial HTML to time
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = display;

    //Timer function for start button
    function timer() {
      timeHandler = setInterval(function() {
        if (time > 0) {
          time--;
          document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = time;
        }
      }, 1000);
    }

    //Stop function for stop button
    function stopTimer() {
      clearTimeout(timeHandler);
    }
//Timer Display 
var minutes = time/60; 
var second = time%60; 
var display = minutes + ":" + seconds;
```

HTML:

```
<h1> Pomodoro Clock</h1>
<!--Place holder for timer-->
<div id="timer" class="circle">Timer</div>
<!--//Start Button-->
<button onclick="setTimeout(timer, 1000);">Start</button>
<!--Stop Button-->
<button onclick="stopTimer()">Stop</button>
```

Comment: Please pos the full code (where you define `display`).

Answer (score 0):

Thie `formatTime` function below will take a number of seconds, and convert it to MM:SS format (including padded zeroes):

```
var time = 1500;
//Must declare timeHandler as global variable for stopTimer()
var timeHandler;
//Set intial HTML to time
document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = display;

//Timer function for start button
function timer() {
  timeHandler = setInterval(function() {
    if (time > 0) {
      time--;
      document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = formatTime(time);
    }
  }, 1000);
}

//Stop function for stop button
function stopTimer() {
  clearTimeout(timeHandler);
}

function formatTime(seconds) {
    //Timer Display 
    var minutes = seconds / 60; 
    var second = seconds % 60;
    return ('0'+minutes).substr(-2) +":"+ ('0'+seconds).substr(-2);
}
```

Comment: updating time using increments and decrements is imprecise. Use difference of start date and current date instead.

Comment: Can you add some explanation of what you did and why you think it is the answer? Responding to a wall of code with no question with a wall of code with no explanation doesn't feel like it has long-tail value.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to use `clearInterval`, then you don't update your `display` every second

[check this fiddle out](https://jsfiddle.net/8eqenpey/3/)